# Inline frame java script functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

From inline frame's page JavaScript function I want to call a parent container JavaScript function .Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 window.parent.function_name();
```

But only if iframe and main page comes from the same domain

Comment: That should be `window`. With a lower case "w". JavaScript is case sensitive.